# Running Python in VSCode on Mac pro

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

I used to use vscode before on my mac pro and there was no issue. After a few months, I decided to code again but now when I run my code I get the following error:

[Running] python -u "/var/folders/29/bhp2ctqx2g72kd6xph6018cr0000gn/T/tempCodeRunnerFile.python"
/bin/sh: python: command not found

[Done] exited with code=127 in 0.01 seconds

If I try to run the code in the terminal with python filename.py I get the same issue. Whats the fix, Im new to Linux and working with directories.

Comment: Linux or macOS? The question in its current format is impossible to be answered.

Comment: Sorry, I should say its on a mac book pro not linux my fault.

Comment: Then edit your question to reflect that and don't waste time of others. You should also disclose your Mac Pro model and its macOS version. What have you changed recently? Upgraded to latest macOS and/or Xcode? Those actions alter the system significantly and can invalidate previous working Python installation.